# Matrix object has no attribute nodes networkX python

Tags: python, networkx

I'm trying to represent some numbers as edges of a graph with connected components. For this, I've been using python's networkX module.
My graph is G, and has nodes and edges initialised as follows:

```
    G = nx.Graph()
    for (x,y) in my_set:
       G.add_edge(x,y)

    print G.nodes() #This prints all the nodes
    print G.edges() #Prints all the edges as tuples
    adj_matrix = nx.to_numpy_matrix(G)
```

Once I add the following line,

```
    pos = nx.spring_layout(adj_matrix)
```

I get the abovementioned error. 
If it might be useful, all the nodes are numbered in 9-15 digits. There are 412 nodes and 422 edges.

Detailed error:

```
      File "pyjson.py", line 89, in <module>
      mainevent()        
      File "pyjson.py", line 60, in mainevent
      pos = nx.spring_layout(adj_matrix)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/networkx/drawing/layout.py", line 244, in fruchterman_reingold_layout
      A=nx.to_numpy_matrix(G,weight=weight)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/networkx/convert_matrix.py", line 128, in to_numpy_matrix
      nodelist = G.nodes()
      AttributeError: 'matrix' object has no attribute 'nodes'
```

Edit: Solved below. Useful information: pos creates a dict with coordinates for each node. Doing nx.draw(G,pos) creates a pylab figure. But it doesn't display it, because pylab doesn't display automatically.

Comment: Unclear what you're trying here [`spring_layout`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.layout.spring_layout.html) takes a graph as the first param, not a matrix array

Comment: @EdChum: I didn't know that, thank you. How do I actually get the drawing to appear? nx.draw(G) doesn't throw any errors but it doesn't appear either.

Comment: `sprint_layout` returns the node positions, you need to pass this to `nx.draw` so `nx.draw(G, nx.spring_layout(G))` would work, I can post an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(some of this answer addresses some things in your comments.  Can you add those to your question so that later users get some more context)

`pos` creates a dict with coordinates for each node. Doing `nx.draw(G,pos)` creates a pylab figure.  But it doesn't display it, because pylab doesn't display automatically.

```
import networkx as nx
import pylab as py

G = nx.Graph()
for (x,y) in my_set:
   G.add_edge(x,y)

print G.nodes() #This prints all the nodes
print G.edges() #Prints all the edges as tuples
pos = nx.spring_layout(G)
nx.draw(G,pos)
py.show() # or py.savefig('graph.pdf') if you want to create a pdf, 
          # similarly for png or other file types
```

The final `py.show()` will display it.  `py.savefig('filename.extension')` will save as any of a number of filetypes based on what you use for `extension`.

Answer (score 1):

[`spring_layout`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.layout.spring_layout.html) takes a network graph as it's first param and not a numpy array. What it returns are the positions of the nodes according to the Fruchterman-Reingold force-directed algorithm.

So you need to pass this to `draw` example:

```
import networkx as nx
%matplotlib inline
G=nx.lollipop_graph(14, 3)
nx.draw(G,nx.spring_layout(G))
```

yields:

[image]

Comment: I tried this, do I need to include the nx.lollipop_graph part? 
My program doesn't actually display the graph with this though no errors are thrown.
Edit: Got it once I added a show

Comment: the lollipop graph was just a graph generator, I don't know what graph you're trying to construct but I thought this would demonstrate how it works and how it is displayed. If my answer fully resolved your question then please accept it, there will be an empty tick mark at the top left of the answer, thanks